# I want to setup two events with one click in TSX. I am struggling to figure this out. Any help would be appreciated

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
{!localError ? (
            <div className="create">
                <Button
                    variant=""
                    color=""
                    disabled={title === ""}
                    onClick={transfer} {window.location.reload()}
                >
                    Create and transfer
                </Button>
            </div>
```

```
  onClick={transfer} {window.location.reload()}
```

I can't get the page to refresh after transferring the data.

Comment: Make a wrapper function that will do both actions, only one event can be added via `onClick` binding

Comment: Ah okay, thank you. I am new to this. I will research a wrapper function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an inline function that will call these 2 functions for example :

```
onClick={() => {
  transfer();
  window.location.reload();
}}
```